Where is timedatectl get's it's inital values?
I am doing a study to see how time is being synchronised in Ubuntu 22.04. As any systemd controled system, the service is using systemd-timesyncd.
according to the documentation, when starting, systemd-timesyncd will read the configuration file from /etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf
It can't be /etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf because all the values in it are commented:
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the
#  terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by the Free
#  Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option)
#  any later version.
#
# Entries in this file show the compile time defaults. Local configuration
# should be created by either modifying this file, or by creating "drop-ins" in
# the timesyncd.conf.d/ subdirectory. The latter is generally recommended.
# Defaults can be restored by simply deleting this file and all drop-ins.
#
# See timesyncd.conf(5) for details.

[Time]
#NTP=
#FallbackNTP=ntp.ubuntu.com
#RootDistanceMaxSec=5
#PollIntervalMinSec=32
#PollIntervalMaxSec=2048

Everything is commented out, but when i interogate timedatectl i can see values for npt an such. For  For the love of god i can't understand how timesync is geting it's values.
># timedatectl show-timesync
FallbackNTPServers=ntp.ubuntu.com
ServerName=ntp.ubuntu.com
ServerAddress=185.125.190.56
RootDistanceMaxUSec=5s
PollIntervalMinUSec=32s
PollIntervalMaxUSec=34min 8s
PollIntervalUSec=32s
NTPMessage={ Leap=0, Version=4, Mode=4, Stratum=2, Precision=-25, RootDelay=1.129ms, RootDispersion=213us, Reference=11FD1CFD, OriginateTimestamp=Fri 2024-11-29 21:22:30 GMT, ReceiveTimestamp=Fri 2024-11-29 21:22:33 GMT, TransmitTimestamp=Fri 2024-11-29 21:22:33 GMT, DestinationTimestamp=Fri 2024-11-29 21:22:30 GMT, Ignored=no PacketCount=656, Jitter=252.712ms }

The rest of the mentioned conf files do not exist as far as i can tell.
Any idead before I go crazy?

Even though every line in /etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf is commented out, they still are telling you what the compile time default values are. Indeed, the output from timedatectl show-timesync shows all those default values. Well, there are multiple reverse lookups for ntp.ubuntu.com, but 185.125.190.56 is one of them.

Practically every software in existence today has fallback defaults for configurables in the code, or passed in via configure flags during build.

Hi @DougSmythies the key point on your comment is compile time default values.  I could see the values  in timedatectl show-timesync but I was failing to understand where they were coming from.

The fallback NTP server is set at build time, see the definition of DEFAULT_NTP_SERVERS in debian/rules:
ifeq ($(DEB_VENDOR),Ubuntu)
    DEFAULT_NTP_SERVERS = ntp.ubuntu.com
    SUPPORT_URL = http://www.ubuntu.com/support
    CONFFLAGS_DISTRO =
else
    DEFAULT_NTP_SERVERS = 0.debian.pool.ntp.org 1.debian.pool.ntp.org 2.debian.pool.ntp.org 3.debian.pool.ntp.org
    SUPPORT_URL = https://www.debian.org/support
    CONFFLAGS_DISTRO =
endif

The timing values have defaults in the code, see src/timesync/timesyncd-manager.h:
#define NTP_POLL_INTERVAL_MIN_USEC      (32 * USEC_PER_SEC)
#define NTP_POLL_INTERVAL_MAX_USEC      (2048 * USEC_PER_SEC)

#define NTP_RETRY_INTERVAL_MIN_USEC     (15 * USEC_PER_SEC)
#define NTP_RETRY_INTERVAL_MAX_USEC     (6 * 60 * USEC_PER_SEC) /* 6 minutes */

#define DEFAULT_CONNECTION_RETRY_USEC   (30 * USEC_PER_SEC)

#define DEFAULT_SAVE_TIME_INTERVAL_USEC (60 * USEC_PER_SEC)


Thanks @muru! That seems to be the correct answer.  I didn't know that fallback defaults for configurables was so much common practice. I did thought in one point to look at the distros source code, but i didn't know were it was.
